# Angular 5 - How to reload a component after it is initialized

Tags: angular, reload

I have a search feature in the application. When the user clicks the search button the data is captured in `[(ngModel)]` and passed to a service. The URL is redirected to the HTML of the `SearchComponent`.
This service is injected into the `SearchComponent` and the data is displayed.

When the user enters a new search term, I want to refresh the existing `SearchComponent`. What is the proper way to do this?

### search.component.ts

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../service/data.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-search',
templateUrl: './search.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

userInput : string; 
constructor(private data : DataService) { }

ngOnInit(){
    this.search();
}

search(){

    this.userInput = this.data.searchData;
    console.log('in search init  ' + this.userInput);
    this.data.searchData = "";
 }
}
```

### app.component.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './service/data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private data : DataService){};
   
  title = 'app';
  searchInput: string;
  
  searchButtonclick(){
    console.log('search button clicked   '  + (this.searchInput));
    this.data.searchData = this.searchInput
    this.searchInput = "";
  }

}
```

### app.component.html

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchInput" name="inputfield">
  <a routerLink="/search">
    <button (click)="searchButtonclick()">Search</button>
  </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use `search.component.ts` as child component and use `@Input` :

**app.component.html**

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchInput" name="inputfield">
  <app-search [userInput]="searchInput"></app-search>
</form>
```

**search.component.ts**

```ts
@Input() userInput: string;

ngOnChange(){
    // this will be called each time userInput changes
    this.search(); 
}
```

See [this article](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) for more info

---

If you want that upon click event , all you need is one extra variable something like `searchvalue`

**app.component.html**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchInput" name="inputfield">
  <button (click)="searchButtonclick()">Search</button>
  <app-search [userInput]="searchvalue"></app-search>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
searchvalue:string;
searchButtonclick(){
    this.searchvalue = this.searchInput;
}
```

**search.component.ts**

```
// as above
```

Comment: I want to clear the input field after the user clicks the search button. Would there be any impact?

Comment: Yes any changes on `searchInput` will be reflected to `app-search`

Comment: So it will make a call to the back end every time the value is changed. How can I restrict it to make calls only on search button click ?

Comment: @user2180794 , I have updated the answer for user click also

Answer (score 1):

Ok the trick is that if the model is updated, the component need not be reloaded. The view is automatically updated.

so I edited my data.service to have an observable as follows and then subscribed to this Observable in the search component.

**data.service for sharing the data**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private localData = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  searchData = this.localData.asObservable(); 
  constructor() { }

  updateSearchInput(data : string ){
       this.localData.next(data);
  }
}
```

**search.component**

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
 import { DataService } from '../service/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  userInput : string;
  constructor(private data : DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.search();
  }

  search(){    
    this.data.searchData.subscribe((data) => this.userInput = data );  
  }
}
```